# Overloading << operator - multiple parameters

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, encapsulation

Many of you may know the following in C++:

```
cout << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4; // would produce 1234
```

I'm attempting to recreate the same thing - but instead encapsulate it into a class and increment the values into an integer variables.

I get the error:

error: 'int operator<<(const int&, const int&)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type|

```
class Test
{
private:
    int data;

public:
    Test() { data = 0; }
    void print() { cout << data; }

    friend int operator<<(const int &x, const int &y)
    {
        data += x;
        data += y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test a;
    a << 50 << 20;
    a.print();   //if I had only 1 parameter - it worked and printed out only 50
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your operator is for your test class not just for ints. it must be a member not a friend.

Comment: Take one parameter. Return reference to *this;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> `cout << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4;`

This way this works is as a series of calls with two arguments e.g.

```
(((cout << 1) << 2) << 3) << 4;
```

Which is roughly equivalent to this:

```
cout << 1;
cout << 2;
cout << 3;
cout << 4;
```

So you don't write an `operator<<` taking multiple parameters, it always takes two operands, the left operand and the right operand. The left operand in the example above is `cout` i.e. the `ostream` and the right operand is the `int` being written to it.  The operator returns the left operand, allowing it to be used again in the next operation, and so on for as many `<<` operations as you chain together.

So `cout << 1` returns `cout` again, so that `(cout << 1) << 2` invokes the operator to write 1 to the stream and return the stream, then invokes the operator again on the return value to write 2 to the stream and then returns the stream again.

This is just nonsense:

```
friend int operator<<(const int &x, const int &y)
{
    data += x;
    data += y;
}
```

Where is `data` supposed to come from?  A friend function is not a member of the class, so there is no `this` pointer, so no `this->data`, also you claim to return `int` but don't return anything, and this class is completely unrelated to `Test`. What you've written is an `operator<<` for two ints i.e. for doing `1 << 2` but that operator already exists, it's the bitshift operator, and you can't overload it for built-in types like `int`.

You want:

```
class Test
{
private:
    int data;

public:
    Test() { data = 0; }
    void print() { cout << data; }

    Test& operator<<(int y)
    {
        data += x;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Or as a friend:

```
class Test
{
private:
    int data;

public:
    Test() { data = 0; }
    void print() { cout << data; }

    friend Test& operator<<(Test& t, int y)
    {
        t.data += x;
        return t;
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 for completeness - although I would not bother mentioning `friend`

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, the operator needs to return the `Test` instance:

```
class Test
{
    ...
    friend Test& operator<<(Test& test, int val);
};

Test& operator<<(Test& test, int val)
{
    test.data += val;
    return test;
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much. Could you point me to some docs where I can understand what happens?

Comment: No need to make it a friend and public function, since a simple member function with one parameter will do.

Comment: @AndyCarter any explanation of how `operator<<` works for ostreams from your C++ textbook of choice should do.